# List to Keyword List in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a list of results that I pulled in using Ecto. I want to end up with a keyword list that I can then use to populate a `<select>` inside of Phoenix but I'm unsure how to turn this list into a keyword list like `["1": "Author #1", "2": "Author #2"]`

```
authors = Repo.all(Author)
# How would I create ["1": "Author #1", "2": "Author #2"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A keyword list expects atoms as keys. The good news is that you don't need a keyword list to give to `select`. Here are two approaches:

1. Do it directly in the query:

   ```
   authors = Repo.all from a in Author, select: {a.name, a.id}
   ```
2. Do it on the data:

   ```
   authors = Repo.all Author
   Enum.map(authors, fn a -> {a.name, a.id} end)
   ```

The advantage of the first one is that you will load only the data you need from the table.

Answer (score 4):

Select just the author names using [Enum.map](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Enum.html#map/2)

```
authorNames = authors |> Enum.map(fn a-> a.name end)
```

then use [Enum.zip](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2) to setup the key value pairs

```
1..Enum.count(authors ) |> Enum.map(fn x-> to_string(x) end) |> Enum.zip(authorNames)
```

this will produce soemthing like:

```
[{"1", "Author #1"}, {"2", "Author #2"}]
```

If you want it to be a true keyword list you need the first element to be a atom because keyword lists only use atoms as keys

```
1..Enum.count(authors ) |> Enum.map(fn x-> x |> to_string |> String.to_atom end) |> Enum.zip(authorNames)
```

which will produce

```
["1": "Author #1", "2": "Author #2"]
```

But I've always heard to manage the number of atoms you have carefully and that converting large number of strings to atoms isn't a best practice. Unless you know how many authors your query will return you may need to be careful when converting the key numbers to atoms.

Comment: `["1": "Author #1", "2": "Author #2"]` is a keyword list. `:"1"` is an atom. Try `["1": "Author #1", "2": "Author #2"] == [{:"1", "Author #1"}, {:"2", "Author #2"}]` in iex.

Comment: Instead of using `Enum.map` to get names you can fetch just names with ecto: `Repo.all(from(a in Author, select: a.name))`.

Comment: @EricMeadows-Jönsson thanks, I wasn't 100% sure what `["1": "Author #1", "2": "Author #2"]` was but it makes sense that it's still a keyword list. I've updated my answer to reflect this